# Can I use Authentication Domain Service without Business Application Template?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I try to implement the Authentication/Authorization for an existing silverlight web application. It seems that the Authentication Domain Service can fulfill my requirement. However, the online examples that I can find are all based on Business Application template. I just wonder if I can still easily implement this Authentication Domain Service in my project? Is there any sample, which does not base on MVVM pattern, that I can reference?

BTW, I added a WCF RIA Services Class Library project to enable the WCF RIA service on my Siliverlight project.

Actually, what I really want is only to retrieve the current role name in the Silverlight project.

Thanks,

Wei

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

AuthenticationService.svc is just:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#"
Service="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService" %>
```

edit: The example call I gave was wrong, please ignore that. It was to a web service I defined to log users in, and I got that confused with AuthenticationService.

Here is a link explaining how to implement it without the template:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942451%28v=vs.91%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Peter. But could you give a more detailed example? Also, where can I find my definition of the SilverlightServiceClient class?